# how to pass in multiple input directories for Avro MapRedcue Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, avro

I could process multiple .avro files using comma ',' separation but not folders. I need to process multiple folders/subfolders using AvroMapReduce. Please let me know how I could resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant works for me:

```
/{dir1/subdir1,dir2/subdir2,dir3/subdir3}
```

Comment: I've tried that but getting :Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): Path is not a file:

which class are you using MultipleInputs, FileInputFormat OR AvroInputFormat?

Comment: I run MR jobs with Pig, org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage

Comment: Oh Ok, I'm running from Hadoop system. Perhaps the libs are different. I used to do what you've suggested in the past and it used to work when I used the old Avro lib (Mapred) but not with the newer version (MapReduce).

Comment: Dmitry, the problem was that I had files other than .avro, hence it failed. I removed those files and passed in the folders and it works now. Thanks for your help.